# Understanding code written within a mouse listener

Tags: java, methods, mouselistener

I'm reading code from another developer and trying to understand how this code works:

```
final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(aChart);

chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

   @Override
   public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
      //code
   }

   @Override
   public void chartMouseMoved() {}
});
```

I know it's basically one long method call, but how exactly does this work?  I see a new ChartMouseListener() being instantiated, but what is happening after that?

Comment: Look for `Anonymous Class`

Comment: @Nizil I didn't type up the code in the listener because I'm trying to understand more-so the syntax within the method call.

Comment: @inquisitor Oh ! I better understanding the question :) Well, anonymous class is a way to override and instantiate a class in the same time... More information [in the oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [anonymous instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) of `ChartMouseListener` having 2 overridden methods is being registered as a listener with the component.